# Where do I install DevDemon's Channel Images in EE 3.3?

Tags: error, devdemon, channel-images, ee3, php-errors

I'm trying to install Channel Images on my EE 3.3 site. The install says:

Installing

Within the /system/expressionengine/third_party/ directory, copy the channel_images folder into your sites ./system/expressionengine/third_party/ directory.

Within the /themes/third_party/ directory, copy the channel_images folder into your sites./themes/third_party/ directory.

Go to the Modules area in the ExpressionEngine control panel, find Channel Images in the list, and click Install.

But my back end is not organized that way. In fact, I can find no folders for "third_party." I tried to intuit where the add-on was supposed to be installed, and indeed after doing it I could activate the addon within my site's addon manager.

However, after activating it, I cannot create any new fields. I get the following error:

Error: Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/channel_images_lang.php

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

EE 3's folder structure is organized slightly differently than EE 2.  You'll need to copy the "system/expressionengine/third_party" files to "system/user/addons/" and your "/themes/third_party/" to "themes/user/".